# Cannot update HomeBrew: Permission denied

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to fix some brew doctor error but now after manually erased some files that brew doctor suggested I get the following error when trying to do a brew update :

```
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Error: Failed to update tap: homebrew/versions
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: use `sudo` for the update?

Comment: What are the permissions on `/usr/local/.git`? Sounds like you're perhaps sharing a machine and someone else updated homebrew and, in the course of doing that, took ownership of the `/usr/local` directory tree.

Comment: No the macbook pro is mine.I am not sharing with anybody else.The permissions of /usr/local/.git are Administrator staff

Answer (score 32):

If you are using OSX High Sierra chown operation is not permitted in `/usr/local/` in this case use:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Homebrew/
```

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 13):

I managed to fix this error by fixing the user owner of the /usr/local folder from 504 to Administrator (the user id I am using when I log in to macbook pro terminal).

This was achieved by using this command :

```
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local
```

Comment: I had to run `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local` on Catalina

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local && sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local
```